# Is it possible to call a Given step from a When step in cucumber?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

Let's say I have some scenario like:

```
Feature: Creating Books
  In order to have books to read
  As a user
  I want to create them

  Background:
    Given I am on the book creation page

  Scenario: Creating a book
    When I create the book "Moby Dick"
    Then I should see "Book has been created."
```

and step definitions:

```
Given /^I am on the ([\w\s]+)$/ do |page|
  case page
  when "book creation page"
    visit new_book_path
  else
    visit page
  end
end

Given /^there is a book "([\w\s]+)"$/ do |title|
  steps %Q{
    Given I am on the book creation page
  }
  fill_in 'Title', :with => 'Moby Dick'
  click_button 'Create'
end

When /^I create the book "([\w\s]+)"$/ do |title|
  steps %Q{
    Given there is a book #{title}
  }
end
```

Running cucumber, I find that 'Given there is a book' is understood as a 'When':

```
You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

When /^there is a book Moby Dick$/ do
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end
```

I notice that the [calling steps from steps](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Calling-Steps-from-Step-Definitions) avoids cross-parts of speech. Is that I wish to do possible, without duplicating 'Given there is a book' to 'When there is a book'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I think your code is correct, you can definitely call steps in this manner.  However you have missed the double-quotes from the step name, you are trying to call 'there is a book Moby Dick' but the step you have defined expects to match 'there is a book "Moby Dick"'.  If you make the following adjustment:

```
steps %Q{
    Given there is a book "#{title}"
}
```

It should work fine.  In addition, for a one-line step you can use the `step` method, which is probably more concise in this situation:

```
step "Given there is a book \"#{title}\""
```